# Can't get access token when call in Paypal in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, paypal

I want to get access token from Make your first call in paypal

I am convert Curl to objective c

```
 curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

My Objective c code like these.....

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"]];

    request.tag = 1010;
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setUsername:@"kclientID"];
    [request setPassword:@"kSecrestID"];


    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
     [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept-Language" value:@"en_US"];

    NSMutableData *data1 = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=client_credentials"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [request setPostLength:[data1 length]];
    [request setPostBody:data1];



    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinishedLocation:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailLocation:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Any one have idea what is the problem in these code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seeing references to `ASIFormDataRequest`, it looks like you're using [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which is no longer actively developed nor maintained since 2011.

I would suggest switching to a more recent and maintained library or using Apple built-in libraries.

Using [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html), a simple code to get an access token from Paypal would be:

```
NSString *clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
NSString *secret = @"YOUR_SECRET";

NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", clientID, secret];
NSData * authData = [authString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *credentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[configuration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept": @"application/json", @"Accept-Language": @"en_US", @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Authorization": credentials }];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *dataString = @"grant_type=client_credentials";
NSData *theData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:theData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"data = %@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]);
    }
}];

[task resume];
```

with would give you the following output containing your access token:

```
data = {
    "access_token" = "YOUR_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN";
    "app_id" = "APP-YOUR_APP_ID";
    "expires_in" = 28800;
    scope = "https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*";
    "token_type" = Bearer;
}
```

Comment: I have been successful in fetching access token with the answer you posted. Could you please tell me how can i make following CURL request using objective-c?                       `curl -v https://api.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer WfXdnxmyJtdF4q59ofxuQuAAk6eEV-Njm6puht3Nk3w"` I have trying to achieve this: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/profile_sharing_server.md#retrieve-customer-information-using-a-valid-access-token

Comment: Well, you can follow the same pattern, -H in CURL are headers so you have to provide a new Content-Type (application/json) and add the Authorization field with your token following the syntax used in the curl command. You can remove the HTTPMethod property change on the `NSMutableURLRequest` because they default to GET and you can switch from `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

Comment: Was scratching my head for many days to achieve this using Objective-C. Thank YOU very much. Done!!!

Comment: saved my day and up for you